# jmeter get link content with specific class with xpath extractor from html response

Tags: html, regex, xpath, jmeter

I have an HTTP response that contains lots of links with the class "link product-link", for example:

```
<a href="/a4-nw6179-womens-solid-zip-leg-pull-on-pant-sweat-pants/262361511" class="link product-link" data-external-product-id="0000000000000002088900000000000015725311P"></a>
```

I want to extract one of the links itself to use in another request

```
/a4-nw6179-womens-solid-zip-leg-pull-on-pant-sweat-pants/262361511
```

I wrote

> /html/body/a[contains(@class,'link product-link')]

in the query but it didn't give back what I need. It always returns the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get default value because of **SAXParseException** in Jmeter.

You have to select 'Use Tidy' option as given below.

Use below XPATH query.

```
//a[@class="link product-link"]/@href
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Likely the links are not direct children of `<body>`. So what you need is:

```
//a[contains(@class,'link product-link')]
```

Additionally, you want the `href` attribute of the `<a>` node, so modify the query:

```
//a[contains(@class,'link product-link')]/@href
```

Comment: Why using contains() where = is sufficient for a full match ?

Comment: @sputnick because `=` is an exact match (as expected), while CSS selectors tolerate variations in whitespaces. For instance, `class=" foo bar"` still refer to class `.foo .bar`, although `' foo bar' = 'foor bar'` is false. It's a way for making it more robust. Remember that we are talking about HTML, not XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
string(//a[@class="link product-link"]/@href)
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it, I still get the default value. Maybe i'm doing something else wrong. any ideas what else to check (i'm new with jmeter)?

Comment: Whats is the 'default value' ? Did you try without string() ?

Comment: It's a string I put in the "default value" field, under xpath query field. I removed it now and I still dont get the link. I tried without the string(). I have "href" in the reference name and then i'm using ${href} in the path in a new http request. In the result tree I see only GET http://www.shopyourway.com/ without the path after the "/". Maybe i'm missing some step in the process?

Comment: My XPath is correct, dunno what's wrong on your side